# The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type:

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Im trying to create a constructor for the trail model. I need the constructor because Im modyfing the controller, this is the actual implementation of the controller (I don't think the problem is there):

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Trail>> PostTrail(
        string Name, int CreatorId, Difficulty difficulty, string Description)
    {
      if (_context.Trails == null)
      {
          return Problem("Entity set 'LivetrailsDBContext.Trails'  is null.");
      }

      if (_context.Trails.Any(trail => trail.Name == Name))
        {
            return Problem($"Trail with name {Name} already exists ");
        }

        var creator = _context.Users.Find(CreatorId);
      if (creator == null)
        {
            Problem($"There is no creator with such Id ({CreatorId})");
        }

        Trail trail = new Trail(Name, creator, difficulty, Description);
        _context.Trails.Add(trail);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetTrail", new { id = trail.Id }, trail);
    }
```

So, I created the suitable constructor, but when I run *add-migration* it returns this error:

> No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Trail'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'creator' in 'Trail(string name, User creator, Difficulty difficulty, string description)'.

Here is the Trail class with the constructor:

```
namespace LivetrailsBackend.Models.DataModels
{
    public class Trail: BaseEntity
    {
        [Required, StringLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public User Creator { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int CreatorId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Difficulty Difficulty { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }


        public Trail(string name, User creator, Difficulty difficulty, string description)
        {
            Name = name;
            Creator = creator;
            CreatorId = creator.;
            Difficulty = difficulty;
            Description = description;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the User model:

```
namespace LivetrailsBackend.Models.DataModels
{
    public class User: BaseEntity
    {
        [Required, StringLength(20)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required, EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Trail> Trails { get; set; } = new List<Trail>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a bug in your code. when creator == null the code should return error

```
 if (creator == null)
 {
    Problem($"There is no creator with such Id ({CreatorId})");
    return .... your error code
}
```

and IMHO instead of creator it is much better to use  just a creatorId, you don't need to assign both, fix your constructor too

```
   [Required]
   public int CreatorId { get; set; }
   public User Creator { get; set; }
```